# how to fix firebase local cache corruption

Tags: ios, firebase

I was trying to read the old value from firebase, update it, then save it back with the following code:

```
var unreadChatsRef = usersRef.childByAppendingPath("\(user.objectId!)/unreadChats/\(self.chat.objectId!)")
unreadChatsRef.observeSingleEventOfType(FEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        var msgCnt = snapshot.value as? Int
        msgCnt = (msgCnt ?? 0) + 1
        unreadChatsRef.setValue(msgCnt)
    }
})
```

Previously I made a mistake and used observeEventType instead of single event so by saving the value, it triggers itself to update the value again and again. I stopped my iOS program while seeing this in debug session. Somehow none of the subsequent updates made it to the firebase server. I had the local cache enabled by calling `Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled = true`. So I end up with a cached value different from the value on the server.

What puzzles me is that even if my other iOS chat client updates that number, this iOS device (the code above) continues to see the cached value and can never fetch the correct value from the server. Am I doing something wrong? How do I tell my program to invalidate the cache and fetch a fresh copy from the server?

Comment: Hey Quan, can you mail support@firebase.com with the same details?