# Firestore fails to fetch full document after listener kept firing off continuously

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Ok something really weird happened. Have an app that's about to go into production. This is how the application functions

- There is a **Home Page** which fetches the logged in user's document **every time** the app comes to **foreground**
- This is not a one time fetch but a `listener` so it will also listen for changes as the app is in foreground
- I use this mechanism to keep the user document **up to date** and pass it to other pages in the app
- When app goes to **background**, I remove the `listener`
- The user document has close to ***30 fields***

So I was testing another functionality in app in the **simulator** and everything was working. I parallely ran the app with the ***same user logged*** in on a **real device** and this is what happened after the build:

- As the app came to **foreground** the `listener` fired **without stopping**. I have the code in a such a way that every time the listener fetches the document from firestore, a part of the home page animates. So technically the home page refreshed without stopping
- I killed the app and re-built it and the continuous firestore fetch happened yet again
- So I all together deleted the app and re-built it - Now the continuous firestore fetch stopped

**Here is the PROBLEM:**

- The document has all

> 30 fields on firestore

- But on the real device, it fetches only 2 fields
- I tried re-installing and re-building many times but this is the state

**But on the simulator with the same user logged in, it works fine**.

What could be the issue? Is there some corrupted cache for this particular user? Firestore is a solid product so never encountered anything like this before.

Here is the listener code:

```
    @objc func viewEntersForeground(){
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
        let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(currentUid)
        userListener = ref.addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error{
                let alertController = ErrorAlertController(errorText: "\(error.localizedDescription)", errorTitle: "Something's wrong", viewController: self)
                alertController.showAlertController()
                return
            }
            
            //THE BELOW DICTIONARY FETCHES ONLY TWO FIELDS
            guard let dictionary = snapshot?.data() else {return}
            self.userDictionary = dictionary
            self.user = User(dictionary: dictionary)
            
            self.checkIfUserExists()
            if self.user?.uid == "" || self.user?.uid == nil {
                return
            }
            
            self.passDataToInbox()
            self.passDataToSettings()
            self.checkIfFirTokenExists()
            self.checkIfProfilePictureExists()
            
            if self.user?.userState == 3{
                self.isUserState3 = true
            } else {
                self.userState = self.user?.userState
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898448/how-to-fix-firebase-local-cache-corruption

Comment: Seems like the same issue as the one in the link above

Comment: To start looking at the behavior, is there some debug output with line numbers and file names?